# Software Center in Dark Theme Unreadable

Tags: 14.04, gnome, software-center, themes, gdm

So I am using the dark theme in **gdm** and the text in the software center is unreadable. I found a workaround by changing the font color from the **.css** as follows

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.css
@define-color light-aubergine #DED7DB; -> modify
@define-color super-light-aubergine #F4F1F3; -> modify
```

My question is, is there a neat way to solve it so that anytime I change the theme the text is changed automatically?

Comment: I've been struggling with this same issue using the Adwaita theme with the Global Dark Theme turned off. If I use the Ambiance or Radiance themes, then it works fine, but other applications look strange for Gnome 3. In the same file you listed above, I commented out the two GtkTreeView styles. Cycling through the default installed themes, they all looked fine with this change.

It still feels like a hack to me, but it's better than not being able to read selections.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using the old software centre (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software`) or using Synaptic. The new Software Centre tends to get broken anyway, so if you can I'd reccomend using the older version or even a package manager instead.

Comment: You actually are suggesting to install the **new** software center, the package for the old software center is `software-center`... although this seems unrelated to the question asked here.

Comment: whoop, must've gotten them mixed up XD I'm too busy playing undertale

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not currently a way to do it more cleanly than that - unless you write some solution up yourself.

Now, if you wanted to do that, likely what you'd want to do is have some scripts like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# sets a dark theme
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Some-Dark-Theme"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "Numix-Circle"
cp ~/.path/to/some/dir/softwarecenter-dark.css /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.css
```

And of course, you could have another script do the same thing in reverse - or even just have the script only be concerned with toggling the `softwarecenter.css`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't really a fix for this yet it's not just the software center it's a couple other applications as well but if you want a software center that works with themes use the lubuntu-software-center it's also more stable

Comment: Provide more information for your solution or a workaround.